# Need to exclude spring-orm module from spring boot 2.0 and use an older version of it from a jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-orm

I have a .jar artifact which is technically a DAO layer has been built with an older tech stack.

- Java 1.6
- Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE
- Hibernate 3.5.6-Final
- Maven

I want to add this .jar as a dependency in my new spring boot 2.x project and use as the Data layer of the app.

*New app tech stack:*

- Java 1.8
- Spring Boot 2.1.3
- Spring framework 5
- Gradle

According to my understanding, I added the older jar as a dependency in my build.gradle and excluded spring-orm module. But gradle still pulling latest versions rather than using the version in older .jar dependency.

**build.gradle**

```
group = 'com.test.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        credentials {
            username = "$nexusUsername"
            password = "$nexusPassword"
        }
        url "$nexusUrl"
    }
}

// exluded spring-orm from spring boot 2.x
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-orm'
}

dependencies {
    // my older dao dependency
    implementation "com.my.older.core:dao:0.3.8-SNAPSHOT"

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Somehow I need to make the app use older orm version instead of the new version in spring boot 2.x since the dao .jar is using the older version.

Any lead on this would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: no you don't want to add that jar. You should never mix jars from different versions of a framework. That will lead to strange and severe errors. See if it works with the regular Spring Orm version, if not fix your old dao or don't reuse but rebuild. But never start mixing jars from different versions of a framework. One solution could be to downgrade to an older Spring Boot version to see if a Spring 4.x versions works for your dao.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the insight. Apparently what you're telling is so true. But I'm in a situation where to choose either to reuse that jar or re-write the whole dao layer again in this new app. Probably I should try downgrading to Spring Boot 1.x

Comment: You might be better of rewriting it. If there are entities in there you might be able to reuse them. Then simply use Spring Data JPA to quickly implement the repositories/daos you need.

Comment: Yes you're correct. downgrading spring boot also didn't help, so I'm rewriting it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Depends on what you do, you shouldn't be mixing versions, so stick with the version of shipped with Spring Boot 1.x and try you dao dependency. Don't try to include the old `spring-orm` dependency etc.

Comment: Sure, got it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.springframework:spring-orm:oldversion'
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Never mix different jars from different versions of a framework. That is trouble waiting to happen.